# Should HTML5 web games use the VideoGame or WebApplication schema?

Tags: html5, schema.org, web-applications

I've implemented Microdata with Schema.org for my [online game](http://www.puzzlopia.com/puzzles/symvoids/play).

I've tested it on [Google's test tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.puzzlopia.com%252Fpuzzles%252Fsymvoids%252Fplay), and it seems to work.

If you go to Schema.org, you can see that both `VideoGame` and `WebApplication` types come from `SoftwareApplication`. Then, as my HTML5 games are both *video games* and *web applications*, what is the best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VideoGame](https://schema.org/VideoGame) would be most appropriate as it *is* a [Game](https://schema.org/Game), but you can include VideoGame *and* [WebApplication](https://schema.org/WebApplication) so you can use the properties of both.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoGame">
    <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/WebApplication">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Game Name</h1>
    <span itemprop="browserRequirements">…</span> <!-- A WebApplication property -->
    …
</div>
```

Google Structured Data Testing Tool doesn't appear to support this however.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, if it doesn't work for their Structured Data Testing Tool, maybe it is a bit risky. I'm doing this to enable their Rich Snippets and I need it to work smoothly for them (I feel like all we work for Google). On the other hand, I don't know if this microdata is useful for any other reasons.